# WSO2 DSS: How can I enable debug logging?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I'm testing a complex query for the DSS and ideally I'd be able to see the exact query that the DSS is executing. I didn't see anything in the conf/log4j.properties file pertaining to this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can enable debug logs by putting the following package name in log4j.properties file

```
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core=DEBUG
```